# Android XML Layout - a picture with a TextView on it

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm working on an XML layout in my app and what I want to do is to make an `ImageView` have a piece of text on it (I want to have a `TextView` on it). Anyway, less words and more examples. What I want is something like this:

[image]

I would like to know what is the best way to make it (with an opaque strip and preferably with text that will stretch or shrink depending on the length of name. Though I think I might figure the stretching out by myself).

Comment: You can use absolute layout or frame layout and position and size everything wrt parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `RelativeLayout` with the `ImageView` and `TextView` as its two children

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:background="@drawable/myBackground"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I'm really bad with these `RalativeLayout`s. What will be in my drawable? A strip of an opaque paint? Maybe there is a way without using a drawable but to draw it myself in a program? In case I need a dynamic sized strip

Comment: You could use `@android:color/` or good ole hex coded ARGB as a background too. Ex: `@android:color/red` OR `#BBFFFFFF`

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Chris Stillwell said, set the Alpha property to less than 1:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:background="@drawable/myBackground"
    android:gravity="center" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    textView.setText("Your Text");
    textView.setAlpha(.6f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and addition about the changes using code. I have upvoted your answer but I will mark ChrisStillwell's answer as correct because he was first. Though I still thank you very much